# Is there a way to refactor the c# code having multiple conditions?

Tags: c#

Is there a better way to refactor my below code where I have many conditions in if and else statement

The reason for refactoring is to make code cleaner and readable

```
    public static PaymentOptions GetPaymentOptions_Auto(TestConfigurationCDO testConfiguration, int siteId)
{
    var paymentOptions = new PaymentOptions();

    var paymentOptionList = SitePaymentRepository.GetSitePaymentInfoBySiteId(
        testConfiguration,
        siteId);

    var lowestPriority = paymentOptionList.Min(x => x.Priority);
    var paymentAuto = paymentOptionList.Where(x => x.Priority == lowestPriority).FirstOrDefault();
    
    if (paymentAuto.PaymentType == PaymentMethod.Klarna)
    {
        paymentOptions = new KlarnaOptions();
    }
    else if (paymentAuto.PaymentType == PaymentMethod.PayPalDirect ||
        paymentAuto.PaymentType == PaymentMethod.Braintree ||
    paymentAuto.PaymentType == PaymentMethod.BankTransfer || paymentAuto.PaymentType == PaymentMethod.AdyenDropIn)
    {
        paymentOptions = new ClientCheckoutOptions()
        {
            paymentMethod = paymentAuto.PaymentType
        };
    }
    else if (paymentAuto.PaymentType == PaymentMethod.PayPalExpress)
    {
        paymentOptions = new PaypalOptions();
    }
    else
    {
        paymentOptions = new PaypalOptions();
    }
    return paymentOptions;
}
```

Comment: @canton7 - Can you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as  [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/120114) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Extract the statements into methods.
   Like:
   `paymentAuto.IsKlarnaPayment()`

   This would shorten the `if` statements a bit.
2. At the end you have

   ```
   else if (paymentAuto.PaymentType == PaymentMethod.PayPalExpress)
   {
       paymentOptions = **new PaypalOptions()**;
   }
   else
   {
       paymentOptions = **new PaypalOptions()**;
   }
   ```

   This returns the same `PaymentOption`. So it would be better to remove the last `else if` statement.
3. `paymentAuto` can be null in this scenario (**`FirstOrDefault()`**). This can lead to null reference exception.
4. You can combine this:

   `paymentOptionList.Where(x => x.Priority == lowestPriority).FirstOrDefault();`

   into

   `paymentOptionList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Priority == lowestPriority);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer...

      paymentOptionList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Priority == lowestPriority);

Worked wonders!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You've got lots of tests for `paymentAuto.PaymentType` there, and many of the cases are the same. A switch statement will neaten that up, as it only names `paymentAuto.PaymentType` once, and it encourages you to put all of the cases nicely aligned together in code:

```
public static PaymentOptions GetPaymentOptions_Auto(TestConfigurationCDO testConfiguration, int siteId)
{
    var paymentOptionList = SitePaymentRepository.GetSitePaymentInfoBySiteId(
        testConfiguration,
        siteId);

    var lowestPriority = paymentOptionList.Min(x => x.Priority);
    var paymentAuto = paymentOptionList.First(x => x.Priority == lowestPriority);

    PaymentOptions paymentOptions;
    
    switch (paymentAuto.PaymentType)
    {
        case PaymentMethod.PayPalDirect:
        case PaymentMethod.Braintree:
        case PaymentMethod.BankTransfer:
        case PaymentMethod.AdyenDropIn:
            paymentOptions = new ClientCheckoutOptions()
            {
                paymentMethod = paymentAuto.PaymentType
            };
            break;

        case PaymentMethod.Klarna:
            paymentOptions = new KlarnaOptions();
            break;

        case PaymentMethod.PayPalExpress:
        default:
            paymentOptions = new PaypalOptions();
            break;
    }
}
```

The initial value you were assigning to `paymentOptions` wasn't used, so you can leave that variable uninitialised. The compiler will moan at you if you forget to initialise it somewhere in the `switch` statement.

That `.FirstOrDefault()` *shouldn't* fail to find a matching item. To make sure of this, I changed it to `.First()`, which throws an exception if it can't find a match. `.Where(...).First()` is the same as `.First(...)` (but a bit more expensive), so I changed that as well.

Annoyingly there's no `.MinBy` method in Linq (there are plenty of examples of implementations around, though). If you have this, you can write `var paymentAuto = paymentOptionList.MinBy(x => x.Priority)`.

Comment: Thank you @canton7 - This will work like charm!!!! and more readability and more simpler

Comment: Not able to upvote it:(

Comment: How do I mark this question as resolved

Comment: You've done that, by marking this answer as the accepted answer